# how to fix flutter web http error making http request to a particular web server

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-web, hummingbird

I am trying to make an HTTP request to 000webhost  as below in my flutter web app. The first method is the same as the second, I only changed the URL. However, the first one works but the second does not work. Someone suggested adding more headers but I have no idea which headers to add.

```
// This method WORKS
getMethod()async{

  print("IN GET ....");
  String theUrl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos';
  var res = await http.Client().get(Uri.encodeFull(theUrl),headers: {"Accept":"application/json"});
  //var res = await http.get(Uri.encodeFull(theUrl),headers: {"Accept":"application/json"});
  var responsBody = json.decode(res.body);
  print(responsBody);
  return responsBody;
}



// This DOES NOT WORK
getMethod()async{
  print("IN GET ....");
  String theUrl = 'https://funholidayshotels.000webhostapp.com/fetchData.php';
  var res = await http.Client().get(Uri.encodeFull(theUrl),headers: {"Accept":"application/json"});
  //var res = await http.get(Uri.encodeFull(theUrl),headers: {"Accept":"application/json"});
  var responsBody = json.decode(res.body);
  print(responsBody);
  return responsBody; 
}
```

Comment: Question was framed nicely. Before coming through this question, I thought it was some issue with flutter packages. This question motivated me to make changes in my backend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After struggling with this for some time I figured out the problem was from the server side
I had to add `Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` to `.htaccess` on 000webhost And This solves it for me

Comment: https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ . I used this when I was using flask as the server

Comment: User the cors npm package to achieve this on node or express server. Link for package : https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors . You can use this as a middleware by doing :const cors = require("cors"); app.use(cors())

Answer (score 2):

You can also Add the code below to your php file like so:

```
    <?php
    require('connection.php');
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    ....
    code goes here
    ....
    ?>
```

I Tried this on LocalHost and it worked