# http request is blocked by Cors policy for flutter web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I have an Android, Ios and web app that's using php as a backend. All Api's are working fine in both android and ios but throwing CORS error in web.
Getting error like this

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://example.com/api' from origin 'http://localhost:49168' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I tried to send
headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:49168',
"Origin": "http://localhost:49168"
},
to http request.
Web is working smoothly if i add CORS extension for chrome. Please help me out

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60191683/xmlhttprequest-error-in-flutter-web-enabling-cors-aws-api-gateway?rq=1 ?

Comment: I am using form-data. Where should i add those requests?

Comment: Your API needs to send the Access control allow origin "your domain" / "*" headers. I'd recommend reading up on CORS https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: I already sent in post request but throwing same error

Comment: CORS is not something you control from the front end (Flutter). Your PHP API must send these headers. It is outlined in the link I sent.

Comment: sent like 
await http.post(url,
          headers: {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*", },// Required for CORS support to work,
          body: {
            .......
          });

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cross-Origin Request Headers(CORS) with PHP headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719276/cross-origin-request-headerscors-with-php-headers)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228794/discussion-between-kavana-shettigar-and-james).

Answer (score 6):

The same problems hit me two weeks ago. For me, the following error is giving me a wrong direction to checking the problem:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://example.com/api' from origin
> 'http://localhost:49168' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

It says something about the request, but turns out it had nothing to do with the request. And it also had nothing to do with the web server (`apache` or `nginx` in my case).

The solution is by adding header to the response (yes, **response**) from your backend. I don't know the solution for `php` code, but I use the following code in my golang backend to add header to the response:

```
// Adding CORS header to response.
func (server *WebUploadServer) addCorsHeader(res http.ResponseWriter) {
    headers := res.Header()
    // use your domain or ip address instead of "*".
    // Using "*" is allowing access from every one
    // only for development.
    headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    headers.Add("Vary", "Origin")
    headers.Add("Vary", "Access-Control-Request-Method")
    headers.Add("Vary", "Access-Control-Request-Headers")
    headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Origin, Accept, token")
    headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS")
}


// Here we handle the web request.
func (server *WebUploadServer) webHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("Endpoint hit")

    server.addCorsHeader(w) // Here, we add the header to the response

    switch r.Method {
    case "POST":
        // do something here.
    case "OPTIONS":
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    case "GET":
        fallthrough
    default:
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Sorry, only  POST method is supported.")
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right. Those headers belong to the response, not request. So it's the backend that has to handle that CORS. It reminds me of my answer in the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe/54342285#54342285

Comment: Great answer. I do have CORS enabled in my backend, i.e. the response has the header `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"`. But it still gives me this error. Are you sure I need all the other headers as well?

Answer (score 0):

I want to post my solution because my server's CORS is configured correctly (as far as I can tell) and the blocking appears to be a result of the Flutter framework. I think that I solved my problem by removing the `Cookie` from the request headers. From my understanding, this is the equivalent of `withCredentials = false`. I added the following code right before I made my request:

```dart
request.headers.remove('Cookie');
```

Hopefully this helps someone as I found resolving CORS issues to be the hardest part of publishing a Flutter app to the web. If anyone has any better insight into this issue, then I'm definitely happy to learn more.

If you need to know about my environment, then I am using Django, Django REST framework, and `django-cors-headers`:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...,
    "corsheaders",
    ...,
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...,
    # Place CorsMiddleWare above any middleware that may return a response.
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    ...,
]

# Allow CORS from the following domains.
# See: https://github.com/adamchainz/django-cors-headers/tree/main
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGIN_REGEXES = [
    r"^https://\w+\.your-domain\.com$",
]
```

I have also configured the following for Flutter:

1. I have added `--disable-web-security` to `$FLUTTER_SDK/packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/web/chrome.dart`
2. I find it necessary to run `flutter clean & flutter pub get`  before `flutter build web --web-renderer html`.
3. I find that `--web-renderer html` is necessary.

Here is my code for making a POST request from my Flutter app:

```dart
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

// Define your request.
final client = http.Client();
final request;
final body = jsonEncode(data); // Here you can pass your data.
String idToken = await getUserToken(); // In my case I'm passing a user token.
String url = 'your-api.com';

// Define your headers.
final headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
  'Accept': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'Bearer $idToken',
}

// Create a POST request.
request = http.Request('POST', Uri.parse(url))
  ..headers.addAll(headers)
  ..body = body;

// Ensure the client doesn't add cookies.
request.headers.remove('Cookie');

// Get the response.
final response = await client.send(request).then(http.Response.fromStream);
```