# Flutter Web: Not loading Images from the FirebaseStorage (Blocked by CORS policy)

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

Flutter Web is not loading Images from the FirebaseStorage. It was working fine ago but suddenly stopped working and I am getting this in Chrome console

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/lucy-everywhere.appspot.com/o/users%2F7brmE7qbCOZpP1QlZNhf5fr3LoJ3%2Fimages%2FthumbImage?alt=media&token=3ca3b6fb-69b7-4b18-9737-34ca175e1f7e' from origin 'http://localhost:33797' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

and in AndroidStudio

```
======== Exception caught by image resource service ================================================
Failed to load network image.
Image URL: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/lucy-everywhere.appspot.com/o/users%2FXsKVmUCenDNE3CDabA6zCi7HwOy2%2Fimages%2FthumbImage?alt=media&token=8afb91fb-6c02-44ef-97b1-e8627b4bc042
Trying to load an image from another domain? Find answers at:
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/web-images
====================================================================================================
```

Simply I am loading it with

```
String url = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/lucy-everywhere.appspot.com/o/users%2F7brmE7qbCOZpP1QlZNhf5fr3LoJ3%2Fimages%2FthumbImage?alt=media&token=3ca3b6fb-69b7-4b18-9737-34ca175e1f7e"

Image.network(
       url,
      height: 50,
      width: 50,
     ),
```

I found a relevant question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66222832/http-request-is-blocked-by-cors-policy-for-flutter-web), but it's not helping me.