# Flutter http error when I try to use code that works in dart

Tags: android, flutter, http, dart, setstate

I am new to flutter and I want to create app that will help me solve chemist equations, for that I created this function:

```
    void main() {
  String m = "H2O";
  String n = "H2O";
  parser(m, n);
}

parser(m, n) async {
  var client = Client();
  Response response = await client
      .get(Uri.parse('https://chemequations.com/ru/?s=$m+%2B+$n&ref=input'));
  var x = parse(response.body);
  print(x.getElementsByClassName("equation main-equation well")[0].text);
}
```

This construction works in dart really well and prints in console right result, but in flutter I wanted to use it with SetState method, but I can't even print result in console. It throws an error:

```
Error: XMLHttpRequest error.
```

Help me please. Thanks

Comment: Take a look at this question, hopefully something here will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60191683/xmlhttprequest-error-in-flutter-web-enabling-cors-aws-api-gateway

Comment: that doesn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error happens because I launched application in web. Just started debugging from mobile emulator and error disappeared