# Flutter unable to connect API XMLHttpRequest error in flutter

Tags: flutter, web, flutter-web, flutter-web-browser

> Flutter unable to connect API when I try to run web app
> I'm using auth api it's working fine with android and iOS but I'm unable work on flutter-web.
> here are error

```
Login Button Pressed
Error: XMLHttpRequest error.
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/core_patch.dart 910:28                get current
packages/http/src/browser_client.dart 69:22                                                                                    <fn>
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1685:54                                              runUnary
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 159:18                                        handleValue
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 766:44                                        handleValueCallback
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 795:13                                        _propagateToListeners
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 592:7                                         [_complete]
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/stream_pipe.dart 61:11                                         _cancelAndValue
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/stream.dart 1288:7                                             <fn>
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 334:14  _checkAndCall
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 339:39  dcall
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/html/dart2js/html_dart2js.dart 37301:58                              <fn>
    at Object.createErrorWithStack (http://localhost:61429/dart_sdk.js:5080:12)
    at Function._throw (http://localhost:61429/dart_sdk.js:20337:18)
    at Function.throwWithStackTrace (http://localhost:61429/dart_sdk.js:20334:18)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:61429/dart_sdk.js:40851:18)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:61429/dart_sdk.js:40708:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:61429/dart_sdk.js:40714:13)
    at http://localhost:61429/dart_sdk.js:36191:9
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [XMLHttpRequest error in flutter web \[Enabling CORS AWS API gateway\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60191683/xmlhttprequest-error-in-flutter-web-enabling-cors-aws-api-gateway)

Comment: @YeasinSheikh nope